# iPhone Default.png not working in Build and Archive

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, default.png

I have a problem when I try to install an iphone application to the device. The problem is that, the Default.png cannot be shown.

The situation is like this:
- I've already named the file as "Default.png" instead of "default.png".
- It works fine on iPhone/iPad Simulator (for Default~iphone.png/Default@2x~iphone.png/Default~ipad.png)
- It works fine when I directly build the application to the device via the USB cable (in iphone sdk)
- It does not work when I build and archive the project and install it via the internet. No Default.png is shown, it only shows a black screen with the status bar. (While I've already made it hidden in info.plist)

I've tried to clean all builds and rebuilds the project. I also try to uninstall the app in my device and install it again. It still not working.

Does anyone has the same problem? Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue a few times. Rebooting the device helped. It seems to be an issue of update OTA installations. Hadn't time yet to investigate details when this happens.